# Active region in BJT in a Common emitter configuration

Tags: bjt, saturation, common-emitter

In BJT for working in active region  for a common emitter configuration emitter and base should be in forward bias and base and collector should be in reverse bias. But in case of voltage we say that base-collector voltage should be less than 0.4V.[image]

But if V(base)-V(collector)=0.1 (suppose) then base-collector junction will be in forward bias that means it will enter into saturation mode. But book says it will remain in active mode. How is it possible?

Comment: For one, 0.1V isn't enough to bias any pn junction into conduction, unless you have some really weird semiconductor.

Comment: that means i will not get any collector current?

Comment: Carefully study the BJT in active mode again, The B-C PN junction will not be in **forward mode** to allow Ic to flow. So there will be a collector current despite the B-C junction being not forward biased. That is basically the whole point of a BJT in active mode.

Comment: No--it means your base-collector junction is not forward biased.

Comment: then can i say that V(collector)-V(base)>-0.4V?

Comment: You can say that elephants are green as well. Doesn't mean it is true. What you mean is: *in **active mode** V(collector)-V(base) > -0.4V* That is basically what it says in the picture. That 0.4 V is just a **rough estimate** and also not a **hard limit**. The transition between saturation and active mode is quite gradual.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bipolar I_V plot; saturation is the far left region; notice all the lines merge in "saturation", not good for linear amplification but good for switches.

[image]

Here is the circuit used to produce that plot

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2feXTwV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>